# Scala convert tuple of types to tuple of generic of types

Tags: scala, generics, types

Say I have type `a` defined as a tuple of types

```scala
type a = (Int, String, Int)
```

and I define generic class `Foo` as

```scala
class Foo[A]{}
```

is there any method is Scala (preferably native Scala) that can convert `a` to `b`, a tuple of generic of types?

```scala
type b = (Foo[Int], Foo[String], Foo[Int])
```

Comment: Does tuple always have 3 elements?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this is not really possible with native scala without `shapeless` or macro on typelevel in scala 2.*, it is possible to create a function that maps the value of type a to value of type b. One thing you should do is to define typeclass `trait LiftFoo[T]`
which has a single method `def lift[T](t: T)(implicit instance: LiftFoo[T]): Foo[T]` and make implementations for all types you ever want.

Then you can map your tuple with the polyfunction:

```scala
object Bla{
  import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._
  import shapeless.syntax._
  import shapeless.poly._
  case class Foo[T](t: T)
  trait LiftFoo[T] {
    def liftImpl(t: T): Foo[T]
  }
  object LiftFoo {
    def lift[T](t: T)(implicit instance: LiftFoo[T]): Foo[T] = instance.liftImpl(t)
  }
  implicit val liftInt: LiftFoo[Int] = {Foo(_)}
  implicit val liftString: LiftFoo[String] = {Foo(_)}
  implicit val liftDouble: LiftFoo[Double] = {Foo(_)}

  val a: (Int, Int, String, Double) = ???
  object LiftFooPoly extends Poly1 {
    implicit def onLiftable[T: LiftFoo] = at[T](LiftFoo.lift[T])
  }
  val b = a.map{LiftFooPoly}
}
```

However, scala 3 (i.e. Dotty) will allow do this on type level with [type lambdas](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/type-lambdas-spec.html) and [match types](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/match-types.html). Typelambda allows types of form `type LiftFoo[T] = [T] =>> Foo[T]` 
and match types and tuples in scala 3 now ressemble HList and you could recursively traverse through its elements with [match types](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/match-types.html):

```
  type TupleLiftFoo[Xs <: Tuple] <: Tuple = Xs match
    case Unit => Unit
    case x *: xs => LiftFoo[x] *: TupleLiftFoo[xs]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 3, you can do simply:

```scala
type b = Tuple.Map[a, Foo]
```

And on value level you can do e.g.:

```scala
(1, "bar", 2) map { [T] => (x: T) => new Foo[T] }
```

Comment: `new` not needed.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, there is no way to do it with Scala 2.x without using some sophisticated type-level magic (in this case Shapeless). My implementation uses a generic representation and contains some comments to label some auxillary things.

In order to fully understand how generic representations work, though, you have to read at least the first couple of chapters of [The Shapeless Guide](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html).

```scala
object Demo extends App {

  import shapeless._
  import syntax.std.tuple._
  import poly._

  // Generic representation of the input type
  val tupleGen = Generic[(Int, String, Int)]

  // Generic representation of the output type
  val tupleFooGen = Generic[(Foo[Int], Foo[String], Foo[Int])]

  // The type we want to lift all tuple members into
  class Foo[A] {}

  // The instance of the input type
  val input = (42, "four two", 43)

  // The "natural transformation" thing
  object liftFoo extends (Id ~> Foo) {
    def apply[T](t: T): Foo[T] = new Foo[T] {}
  }

  // Having done all the prep work, the conversion is really easy
  val result: (Foo[Int], Foo[String], Foo[Int]) =
    tupleFooGen.from(tupleGen.to(input).map(liftFoo))

  println(result)
}
```